# How to add attribute to class in python

Tags: python, oop, attributes

I have:

```
class A:
        a=1
        b=2
```

I want to make as

```
setattr(A,'c')
```

then all objects that I create it from `class A` has `c` attribute.
i did not want to use inheritance

Comment: Have you tried `A.c = 3`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There're two ways of setting an attribute to your class;

First, by using **setattr(class, variable, value)**

**Code Syntax**

```
setattr(A,'c', 'c')
print(dir(A))
```

**OUTPUT**

You can see the structure of the **class A** within attributes

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', 
'__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', 
'__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', 
'__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', 
'__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 
'__weakref__', 'a', 'b', 'c']

[Program finished]
```

---

Second, you can do it simply by assigning the variable

**Code Syntax**

```
A.d = 'd'
print(dir(A))
```

**OUTPUT**

You can see the structure of the **class A** within attributes

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', 
'__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', 
'__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', 
'__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', 
'__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 
'__weakref__', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

[Program finished]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can you static or class variables.

You can do A.c in your Code.

When we declare a variable inside a class but outside any method, it is called as class or static variable in python. Class or static variable can be referred through a class but not directly through an instance.

You can refer this
[https://www.tutorialspoint.com/class-or-static-variables-in-python#:~:text=When%20we%20declare%20a%20variable,not%20directly%20through%20an%20instance](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/class-or-static-variables-in-python#:%7E:text=When%20we%20declare%20a%20variable,not%20directly%20through%20an%20instance).

Answer (score 1):

Just add this line to your code:

```
A.c = 3
```

And then if you do:

```
print(A.c)
```

It will output:

```
3
```