# Create dynamic class attributes

Tags: python

i have a predefined class. I want to create class attributes whose names can be decided at run time only.
outside of class i append my required name into the  `globals()` dict but how to do the same for classes

my attempt at it is given below:

```
class test:
 def __init__(self,x):
  globals()[x]=''
```

the result was a global variable added instead of class variable

Comment: [Welcome to Stack Overflow.](/tour) Won't `exec` work? And please indent the code properly. You're trying to create this kind of dynamic variable for all instances of this class, right?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65547990/765091 . If you use the `setattr` solution there, the attribute name can be set at runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the `__dict__` attribute which acts like a `globals()` but for a localized instance of a class

```
class test:
 def __init__(self,x):
  self.__dict__[x]=''
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `setattr`.

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self, x):
        setattr(self, x, '')
```